# How do I remotely wake my Mac over Wi-Fi?

Tags: macos, mac, network, wifi

I am running a server on my Mac mini at home (using the OS X Server app). I would like to access my home network using it's VPN server, but I understand that I can only do this while it's awake. I have already configured my Mac's server to use its IP address for Wi-Fi (for some DNS settings etc), and so connecting it via ethernet would mean that I would have to change quite a few settings...

I'm running OS X Mountain Lion 10.8

How can I do this without having to connect my Mac to my router via ethernet?

I've searched the site and can't find an answer that makes sense to me since they appear out-dated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Use an Apple Airport or other router that implements [Bonjour sleep proxy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sleep_Proxy_Service) (optional step)
2. Configure your Mac to allow wake from Wi-Fi in the power adapter section of Energy Saver
3. Use [Remote Desktop](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/apple-remote-desktop/id409907375?mt=12) or an equivalent tool to send the [Wake-on-lan (WOL)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wake-on-LAN) packet to your router that will then deliver it to your sleeping Mac.

Comment: Unfortunately my ISP doesn't let me use my own router... But the moment I have access to my Mac mini I'll enable the "wake from Wi-Fi option" and see how it goes. Thanks!

Comment: Perfect - you don't need a router that proxies bonjour, so unless your router doesn't send the WOL packet, you should be good to go. If it doesn't work, you could always ask your ISP to put "their" router in total bridge mode and place your own router so you can control things to your needs and likings.